# How should I ask 'is there a better way' type questions, with a known answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

Generally I try hard enough to answer my own questions before asking that I have at least a partial or clumsy solution to my problem. I sometimes think it would still be worth asking the question, if it's a good one, and hasn't been asked yet. What's the best way to do this?

Ask the core question, then post my own partial or clumsy solution as an answer, then wait and see if anyone comes up with something better?

Ask the question without my solution, wait, and only post my solution if nobody else answers?

Ask the question, and include my solution in the question?

Ask the question as 'Is there a better way to do this?' - This is technically the question I'm asking - but I hate this approach, because the question title has little room to be about the subject of the question itself, making question less useful to the community.

For example, I've been doing some signals analysis stuff. I'm not an expert in this area, but there are some incredibly slick ways of doing things sometimes using transforms, etc. that I may not be aware of. I may come up with a way works to do something, but then I realize it requires lots of code, may take some time, or doesn't fit all fringe cases. There may or may not be a better 'slick' way to do it out there, but I'd like to ask the question anyway. I'd also like to post my solution, somehow, in case nobody else has a better way, or my solution helps someone come up with a better solution.

Comment: If you want people to review your solution then you should be posting on code review, not on SO.  You should be posting on SO if there's a problem that you're looking for a solution for.

Comment: No, I'm not  talking about a code review. I'm talking about the underlying method, algorithm, or mathematical approach.

Comment: Why do you think those things shouldn't be brought up in a code review?

Comment: Because there are many legitimate ways to do something, depending on what you want. Each one may be coded well or poorly. I'm not interested in a discussion about the coding. That's a separate issue to me. The questions I'm talking about  are not about code. They are about ideas and math.

Comment: Reviewing whether the approach to solving the problem is appropriate is a very important part of a good code review.  Analyzing if there would be a better approach to solving the problem is *extremely* important in a good code review.

Comment: Perhaps this was the wrong place to ask questions about this, but I more frequently am looking at stuff from the math, signals analysis, matlab, etc. communities. I'm a scientist, not a programmer. No disrespect to those who visit code review but I have seen nothing in the questions or answers there to indicate that those who commonly frequent that forum would be qualified to even understand the questions I have, let alone give useful feedback. Because they are in a different field. And that forum has a different purpose.

Comment: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314272/839601)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should:

> Ask the core question, then post [your] own partial or clumsy solution as
>   an answer, then wait and see if anyone comes up with something better?

That way:

- Your question will only include a well-framed question
- Your answer will only include an attempt at answering your question
- Users are free to:

  - Vote on your question and answer
  - Add their own, possibly better answers

Be aware that if other users think that you are seeking a review of your work rather than asking a focused question, then they may close/up/down vote accordingly (or recommend using the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if it is a coding question).